# Invalid prop for child component, despite using shallowMount

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, stub, vue-props

I am testing a Vue component that includes a child component. That child components takes 2 props.

In my snapshot test for the parent component, I shallowMount it (so the child component shouldn't render). However, I keep getting a warning saying:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "distance". Expected String with value "undefined", got Undefined
```

I don't understand why the prop would matter here, since I'm using `shallowMount`

The child component is nested in my parent component like so:

```
   <template>
      <ChildComponent :distance="userRecord.distance" :time="userRecord.time" />
   <template>
```

The snapshot test I have is:

```
   test('component matches snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(userDistance, { store, localVue, });
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

If I comment out all my tests that rely on `shallowMount` I no longer get the warning. Do I need to stub out the props for the child component? I have used shallowMount before with a component that has child components, and have never had to do that before.